# UV4L WebRTC demo seemingly not working, how to fix?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, uv4l

There is a demo which comes with UV4L demo OS for Raspberry PI, https://raspberry:8080/stream/webrtc. When i run it on a macOS computer (Firefox browser), and select that a screen is to be shared, it always says 'no suitable video device found!' and apparently doesn't connect anywhere. Same happens when i go there on a Chromium browser on a Raspberry PI itself. There doesn't seem to be any error messages anywhere - some deprecation warnings but no more than that:

```
onopen()  webrtc:197:25
navigator.mozGetUserMedia has been replaced by navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia  webrtc:251:32
WebRTC interfaces with the “moz” prefix (mozRTCPeerConnection, mozRTCSessionDescription, mozRTCIceCandidate) have been deprecated.  webrtc:105:25
{"iceServers":[{"urls":["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302","stun:192.168.0.101:3478"]}]}  webrtc:104:21
onaddstream is deprecated! Use peerConnection.ontrack instead.  webrtc:107
peer connection successfully created!  webrtc:110:21
URL.createObjectURL(MediaStream) is deprecated and will be removed soon.  webrtc:255:60
call(), request={"what":"call","options":{"force_hw_vcodec":false,"vformat":"60"}}  webrtc:193:25
message =message  webrtc:281:25
```

Where shall i look into?

Clarification: i can see my desktop in a 'local' box, so sharing has been successful, same on Raspberry PI. But it never goes to the other side, i can't even use the data channel - it is greyed out - so apparently no connection happens, at all.

Comment: https://blog.domski.pl/uv4l-on-raspberry-pi-running-debian-buster/  - This can help you. there is a problem in buster. So you could go back to stretch or try and fix it using that guide

Answer (score 1):

The following command runs an instance of UV4L that allows to mirror your desktop or window to the Raspberry Pi HDMI display. Note that you must pass the SSL certificates `.key` and `.crt` (see the UV4L installation instructions to know how to generate them):

```
uv4l --enable-server --driver dummy --server-option '--use-ssl=yes' --server-option '--ssl-private-key-file=/home/pi/selfsign.key' --server-option '--ssl-certificate-file=/home/pi/selfsign.crt' --verbosity=7 --server-option '--enable-webrtc-video=no' --server-option '--enable-webrtc-audio=no' --server-option '--webrtc-receive-video=yes' --server-option '--webrtc-renderer-fullscreen=yes' --server-option=--webrtc-renderer-window=0 0 1920 1080 --server-option '--webrtc-receive-datachannels=yes' --server-option '--webrtc-receive-audio=yes' --auto-video_nr --server-option '--webrtc-receive-audio=yes --server-option '--port=9000'
```

You can then access the WebRTC streaming page at:

https://raspberry:9000/stream/webrtc

You must explicitly enable screen sharing in firefox or chrome according to the instructions written in the the same page.

Answer (score -1):

I would check if the camera module on the pi itself is attached correctly. Did you try to capture a test image using something like`raspistill -o test.jpg` yet? I've seen the 'No Suitable devices found' problem come up when I either didn't enable the camera on `raspi-config` or I didn't insert the camera's ribbon cable correctly. You can also check if you've connected the GPIO corresponding pins right.

Comment: There is no camera module on PI and no intention to have one. I was planning to stream H264 video from a Mac to Raspberry to display it on its HDMI monitor.